# How to SQL the ten most upvoted questions for the ten most used tags (in SEDE)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, dataexplorer

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE), I'm trying to get the ten most upvoted questions for the ten most used tags (i.e. JavaScript, HTML, ...).

I see how to get the most used tags:

```
select Id, TagName, Count
from Tags t
order by count desc
```

Now for each tag, I'd like to get the top ten upvoted questions. I need some sort of Join I guess. The problem is that in the `Posts` table, `Tags` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [the SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). Use the `PostTags` table to link tags to questions.

Then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the top 10 questions per tag.

Here's one way ([**See it live in SEDE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1015241/top-10-questions-for-each-of-top-ten-tags)):

```
WITH topTags AS (
    SELECT TOP 10
                t.Id,
                t.TagName,
                t.Count,
                tagRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Count DESC)
    FROM        Tags t
    ORDER BY    t.Count DESC
)
SELECT
        qbt.TagName     AS [Tag],
        --qbt.tagRank     AS [Tag Rank],
        qbt.Count       AS [Q's for Tag],
        qbt.Score       AS [Qst Score],
        qbt.Id          AS [Post Link],
        qbt.qstRow      AS [Rank in tag]
FROM (
    SELECT
                tt.TagName,
                --tt.tagRank,
                tt.Count,
                q.Score,
                q.Id,
                qstRow = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt.Id ORDER BY tt.Id, q.Score DESC)
    FROM        topTags     tt
    LEFT JOIN   PostTags    pt  ON  pt.TagId = tt.Id
    LEFT JOIN   Posts       q   ON  q.ID = pt.PostId
) qbt
WHERE       qbt.qstRow <= 10
ORDER BY    qbt.Count DESC,
            qbt.Score DESC
```